# Jekyll i18n Error

Tags: ruby, localization, jekyll, liquid

I installed i18n gem and plugin to localize the dates, but when I serve the site I get the following error:

```
Malahovas-MacBook-Pro:test Svetlana$ rake
Configuration file: /Users/Svetlana/Desktop/test/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/Svetlana/Desktop/test
       Destination: /Users/Svetlana/Desktop/test/_site
      Generating... 
  Liquid Exception: Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "2015-12-01" given. in _includes/footer.html, included in _layouts/post.html
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "2015-12-01" given.
```

In footer.html I have the following code:

```
<time datetime="{{ page.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}">
    {{ page.date | localize: "%d %B %Y" }}
</time>
```

Here is the code for the plugin `i18n_filter.rb`:

```
require 'i18n'

LOCALE = :ru # set your locale

# Create folder "_locales" and put some locale file from
# https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale
module Jekyll
  module I18nFilter
    # Example:
    # {{ post.date | localize: "%d.%m.%Y" }}
    # {{ post.date | localize: ":short" }}
    def localize(input, format=nil)
      load_translations
      format = (format =~ /^:(\w+)/) ? $1.to_sym : format
      I18n.l input, :format => format
    end

    def load_translations
      unless I18n::backend.instance_variable_get(:@translations)
        I18n.backend.load_translations Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../_locales/*.yml')]
        I18n.locale = LOCALE
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is a collection document. After running build with `--trace` I get:

```
Malahovas-MacBook-Pro:test Svetlana$ jekyll build --trace
Configuration file: /Users/Svetlana/Desktop/test/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/Svetlana/Desktop/test
       Destination: /Users/Svetlana/Desktop/test/_site
      Generating... 
  Liquid Exception: Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "2015-12-01" given. in _includes/footer.html, included in _layouts/post.html
/Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:124:in `rescue in render': Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "2015-12-01" given. (Jekyll::Tags::IncludeTagError)
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:116:in `render'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/block.rb:109:in `block in render_all'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `each'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `render_all'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in `render'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/template.rb:128:in `render'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/template.rb:138:in `render!'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:92:in `render_liquid'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:134:in `place_in_layouts'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:56:in `run'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:291:in `each'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:291:in `block in render'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:290:in `each'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:290:in `render'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:51:in `process'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:56:in `build'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:34:in `process'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/program.rb:35:in `go'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary.rb:22:in `program'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/Svetlana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Some code + url for plugin can help.

Comment: I updated the question with the code for the plugin and the error message after building with `trace` @DavidJacquel

Comment: Did you try to pass something like `2014-01-01 09:49:00` ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I just tried and I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

`I18n.localize` or `I18n.l` expects Date, DateTime or Time argument. `page.date` should actually be  of type `DateTime` or `Time`, but I am assuming that the filter is not loaded and therefor ignored by Jekyll (I added the Liquid-filter loading at the bottom). Here is one possible fix:

**Try to parse the input string before the call to I18n.localize:**

Assuming you have a locale file `ru.yml` in your project directory in a folder named `./locales/`. `i18n.rb` is placed in `./_plugins/i18n.rb`

```
require 'date'
require 'i18n'

path = File.expand_path("../../locales/ru.yml", __FILE__)
I18n.load_path = Dir[path]
I18n.locale = :ru

module Jekyll
  module I18nFilter
    # Example:
    # {{ post.date | localize: "%d.%m.%Y" }}
    # {{ post.date | localize: ":short" }}
    def localize(input, format=nil)
      format = (format =~ /^:(\w+)/) ? $1.to_sym : format

      if input.is_a?(String)
        input = DateTime.parse(input)
      end

      I18n.l input, :format => format
    end

    def translate(key)
      I18n.t key
    end
  end
end

# Add as a filter
Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::I18nFilter)
```

`ru.yml` can be any valid yaml file, containing the locale, e.g.:

```
ru:
  hello: приве́т
```

The conversion to `DateTime` might cause an error if `input` is a malformed String, e.g. empty "" or missing something needed for a date. Minimum would be something like: "2015-01-13".

As an alternative to Jekyll: Check out [Nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/), it seems to be more up-to-date and is easier to extend. It's used at Github and we use it for all static pages on our [localization platform PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I don't get any errors running the server, but localization doesn't work. I get only a string like "2015-01-13".

Comment: Have you added your filter as a plugin? `Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::I18nFilter)` as described here in the Docs: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/ under Liquid Filters

Comment: When added as a filter and regenerating the pages it works for me with 2.4.0

Comment: Actually after I added this line as a filter to the plugin I get the following error: `Liquid Exception: uninitialized constant Jekyll::I18nFilter::LOCALE in _includes/footer.html, included in _layouts/post.html
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  uninitialized constant Jekyll::I18nFilter::LOCALE
Malahovas-MacBook-Pro:test Svetlana$`

Comment: What does `require 'date'` refer to? How can I check if I have this file?

Comment: I adapted the answer to include a valid way of setting a I18n locale previously stored under `PATH_TO_PROJECT/locales/`

The problem is the language loading part. The LOCALE constant is set globally. (which is bad practice in general). If you use my locale loading code you do not need the load_translations method at all. `date` is part of the ruby stdlib and required for using Datetime. I assume that before the i18n file was simply not loaded and therefor no error occured (but also no conversion).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now. The only thing I had to do is change the path to `path = File.expand_path("../../_locales/ru.yml", __FILE__)`. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Now I have another problem. I can run `jekyll serve --watch`, and the site is serving, but not regenerating if I change something. And I get another error: `Liquid Exception: :en is not a valid locale in _includes/footer.html, included in _layouts/post.html
...error:
             Error: :en is not a valid locale`

Comment: Hi, if you're using no locale it seems to fallback to :en at some point (I am unsure where). Try creating an `en.yml` file, like you did with the `ru.yml` file and add it to the path:

`I18n.load_path = Dir["../locales*.{rb,yml}"]`

Not sure about the `../locales` might be single dot or use the File.expand_path method.